# difference between ChildBrowser and InAppBrowser in cordova/phonegap

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap

I have to create new cordova/phonegap application, where I just need to open my websites which contains map and markers on it or any others.

After searching I got plugin like [ChildBrowser](https://github.com/phonegap-build/ChildBrowser) and [InAppBrowser](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/) in cordova/phonegap.

But I am not sure which is best or which is latest and what exactly difference between them?

Please help me to find out solution or any references.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well just few points to help you which you should use.

**Childbrowser**

- childbrowser is not an official plugin.
- It is just the prototype.
- It is not documented very well.
- It is not updated regularly.

**InappBrowser**

- InappBrowser is an official plugin for cordova/phonegap
- It is more flexible.
- It is documented very well.
- It is regularly updated.

So InappBrowser must be the choice as while developing you need the proper documentation and proper support.

hope this helps.

Comment: childbrowser was an official plugin, but it was replaced by InAppBrowser long time ago